# How to solve equations that have derivatives?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y''$ is 2nd order deriv.

$$y'' - y' + y = -\cos(x)$$

we also have this:
\begin{align*}
    2y(0) &= 1 - y'(0)\\
    2&=y'(0) + y(0)
\end{align*}

Solving the 2 equations we get

$y(0) = -1$

However, it does not help us with the general equation..

I tried to integrate it to reduce the 2nd order deriv. $y''.$ But it does not help.
I replace $0$ in the general equation to get any insight.
  \begin{align*}
      y''(0) - y'(0) + y(0) &= -\cos(0)\\
      y''(0) - y'(0) + (-1) &= -1\\
      y''(0) &= y'(0)
\end{align*}
and I'm stuck here. I never solved equations like this one.

Comment: Have you covered some of the theory shown here? 
                    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation

Comment: @S.Dolan no never, thx u

Comment: The answer by @DINEDINE shows the method for your equation but may be difficult to understand without more background reading. See if you can follow it.

Answer (score 3):

> Step 1: Find $a$ and $b$ such that $y_0(x)=a\cos x+b\sin x$ is a solution of your ODE.
>
> Step 2: Solve the quadratic equation $r^2-r+1=0$. Let $r_1$ and $r_2$ the two solutions, thus $y_1(x)=Ae^{r_1x}+Be^{r_2x}$ is the general solution of the ODE
>
> Step 3: The final solution is: $y(x)=y_0(x)+y_1(x)$

Comment: thx, but for the step1, the b is 0 cuz i dont have sin(x) at all.

Comment: so for step1, a  = -1 b = 0, what is y0? is it y or deriv(y)?